# Current Working directory

Tags: directory

How do you change your prompt variable to display the current working directory (pwd), meaning so that when a directory is changed the prompt also changes to reflect the current directory you are in

Comment: Doesn't the default prompt do that?

Comment: No need to change anything, it is the already the default behavior of shell until you are not messing with `PS1` variable.

Comment: @muru well the question would warrant the assumption he is not using the default prompt or not bash ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty certain the default prompt already does that, but here it is, for reference:

```
muru@muru-pc:~$ echo $PS1
${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$
```

The important bit is the `\w` part. You can set it to `\W` for only the name of the current directory (`basename $(pwd)`).

Check out the full list  at [TLDP](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/bash-prompt-escape-sequences.html).